# Trouble With JMC Extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am trying to use the JMC extension for VSCode, but I keep getting an error message that says,

```
"[Error - 1:51:50 PM] Starting client failed
Launching server using command c:\Users\dramo\.vscode\extensions\wingedseal.jmc-4.0.0\out\src\server\JMCServer.exe failed."
```

I checked the file folder, and I noticed that the "server" folder as well as the "JMCServer.exe" file were missing. I was wondering if anyone would be willing to offer some advice on how I should go about fixing the issue, so that the extension works properly?